# Calculate price Index based on Returns in SQL

Tags: t-sql

I am trying to calculate Price Index based on the returns available with me.

Here is a raw data

```
+-----------+--------------+--------------------+
|   Date    |   Returns    | Final Return Index |
+-----------+--------------+--------------------+
| 11/1/2016 |  0.000542159 |        1.000542159 |
| 11/2/2016 | -0.001629094 |        0.998912181 |
| 11/3/2016 |  0.000568779 |        0.999480341 |
| 11/4/2016 | -0.001246407 |        0.998234581 |
| 11/7/2016 |  0.000795611 |        0.999028788 |
| 11/8/2016 |  0.000663507 |        0.999691651 |
| 11/9/2016 | -0.000254819 |         0.99943691 |
+-----------+--------------+--------------------+
```

Column Final Index I have calculated in xls by using

```
1* ( 1+ 0.000542159)
1* ( 1+ 0.000542159) * ( 1+ -0.00162909400) and so on
```

I tried using self Right JOIN and `(EXP(SUM(LOG(NULLIF(t2.InterMediateIndex + 1, 0))))`) but it always multiplies with 1 instead previous calculated index

Any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: So you are wanting a running total?

Comment: Correct running total for different set of accounts in same table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one approach referred to as the "Quirky Update" method.You can read more about in this article by Jeff Moden:
http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/T-SQL/68467/ and in Itzik Ben-Gan's Book:
[https://www.amazon.com/Microsoft-High-Performance-Functions-Developer-Reference/dp/0735658366](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0735658366)

```
-- sample data
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#yourtable') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE #yourtable;
CREATE TABLE #yourtable
(
  someID    int identity primary key,
  [date]    date NOT NULL,
  [Returns] decimal(10,9) NOT NULL,
  [Final Return Index] decimal(10,9) NULL
);

INSERT #yourtable([date], [Returns])
VALUES
('11/1/2016', 0.000542159 ),
('11/2/2016',-0.001629094 ),
('11/3/2016', 0.000568779 ),
('11/4/2016',-0.001246407 ),
('11/7/2016', 0.000795611 ),
('11/8/2016', 0.000663507 ),
('11/9/2016',-0.000254819 );
GO

-- Review what you have
SELECT * FROM #yourtable;

-- The solution
DECLARE @runningTotal decimal(10,9) = 1;

UPDATE #yourtable
SET @runningTotal = [Final Return Index] = @runningTotal+[Returns]
FROM #yourtable WITH (TABLOCKX)
OPTION (MAXDOP 1);

SELECT [date], [Returns], [Final Return Index]
FROM #yourtable;
```

Results:

```
date         Returns         Final Return Index
----------   --------------- --------------------
2016-11-01   0.000542159     1.000542159
2016-11-02   -0.001629094    0.998913065
2016-11-03   0.000568779     0.999481844
2016-11-04   -0.001246407    0.998235437
2016-11-07   0.000795611     0.999031048
2016-11-08   0.000663507     0.999694555
2016-11-09   -0.000254819    0.999439736
```

I don't know what data type you are using in SQL or Excel but you'll have to iron that out to get more precise results. Note the "rules" at the end of the aforementioned article by Jeff Moden.

Alternatively, if you are running SQL Server 2012+ you can use what's referred to as a "window aggregate function" like so:

```
-- sample data
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#yourtable') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE #yourtable;
CREATE TABLE #yourtable
(
  [date]    date NOT NULL,
  [Returns] decimal(10,9) NOT NULL
);

INSERT #yourtable([date], [Returns])
VALUES
('11/1/2016', 0.000542159 ),
('11/2/2016',-0.001629094 ),
('11/3/2016', 0.000568779 ),
('11/4/2016',-0.001246407 ),
('11/7/2016', 0.000795611 ),
('11/8/2016', 0.000663507 ),
('11/9/2016',-0.000254819 );

-- Solution:
SELECT 
  [date], 
  [Returns], 
  [Final Return Index] = 1 + SUM([Returns]) OVER (PARTITION BY (SELECT NULL) ORDER BY date)
FROM #yourtable;
```

Results will be the same as above.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your suggestion . I have one more question if you can help out. If there are two different accounts for same date time series how do I apply group by on it since I cannot add returns to the group by clause.

Comment: I got the solution I will partition by the account. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

**Just for fun,** this is approach will generate and execute some dynamic SQL.

```
Declare @YourTable table (Date date,Returns decimal(18,9))
Insert Into @YourTable values
('11/1/2016',  0.000542159),
('11/2/2016', -0.001629094),
('11/3/2016',  0.000568779),
('11/4/2016', -0.001246407),
('11/7/2016',  0.000795611),
('11/8/2016',  0.000663507),
('11/9/2016', -0.000254819)

Declare @SQL varchar(max) = '>>>'
Select @SQL = @SQL+String
 From (
        Select String=concat(',(|',Date,'|,',Returns,',',Stuff((Select '*' + cast(1.0+Returns as varchar(25)) 
                                                                 From  @YourTable 
                                                                 Where Date<=A.Date 
                                                                 For XML Path ('')),1,1,'') ,')')
        From   @YourTable A
      ) A
Select @SQL = 'Select * From (values '+replace(replace(@SQL,'|',''''),'>>>,','')+') A(Date,Returns,Final)'
Exec(@SQL)
```

**Returns**

```
Date         Returns        Final
2016-11-01   0.000542159    1.000542159
2016-11-02  -0.001629094    0.998912182
2016-11-03   0.000568779    0.999480342
2016-11-04  -0.001246407    0.998234583
2016-11-07   0.000795611    0.999028789
2016-11-08   0.000663507    0.999691652
2016-11-09  -0.000254819    0.999436911
```

**The Generated SQL will look like this**

```
Select Date,Returns,Final=cast(Final as decimal(18,9)) 
 From (values ('2016-11-01', 0.000542159,1.000542159)
             ,('2016-11-02',-0.001629094,0.998370906*1.000542159)
             ,('2016-11-03', 0.000568779,0.998370906*1.000542159*1.000568779)
             ,('2016-11-04',-0.001246407,0.998370906*0.998753593*1.000542159*1.000568779)
             ,('2016-11-07', 0.000795611,0.998370906*0.998753593*1.000542159*1.000568779*1.000795611)
             ,('2016-11-08', 0.000663507,0.998370906*0.998753593*1.000542159*1.000568779*1.000663507*1.000795611)
             ,('2016-11-09',-0.000254819,0.998370906*0.998753593*0.999745181*1.000542159*1.000568779*1.000663507*1.000795611)
      ) A(Date,Returns,Final)
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution . I applied the partition by solution for running total and group by account

Comment: @user1143726 Would have been easy to incorporate if it was in the original request.  That said, I understand the balance of asking a clear, concise question without clouding the issue with too much detail.